# Any way on God's green earth to disable resuming applications after a crash?

Tags: snow-leopard, crash, reboot, restart, resume

Using OS 10.6.8

Every month or two I'll have a hard crash on my MacBook Pro and I'll have to force reboot by holding down the power button. No big deal, I've been doing this on various macs since 1995 since OS version 7.1.

What drives me absolutely bonkers in 10.6.x is that in certain cases like a hard power-cycle, OS X Snow Leopard insists on resuming all 20 or 30 applications I had running before the hard reboot.

Is there some way to tell the OS just never ever ever (ever!) to resume my applications at boot time? I've done everything I can via system preferences and tinkertool of course.

Please help! It takes literally 20-30 minutes for my computer to get up and going in some cases (16 GB RAM, tons of applications running) and if this happens while I'm with a client it's incredibly embarrassing.

I just want a fresh start. Do I have better options in 10.7+?

Comment: Something's not happening, here, with your maintenance/repair routines. My long experience on several iterations of MBPro is that hard crashes are not usual. Ever. In fact, hard crashes pretty much ended with the WallStreet. Except for that 15" PB lemon years ago, Apple replaced its motherboard repeatedly. Do you get kernel panics? This can all be fixed ...

Comment: It's incredibly rare that I get a crash -- mostly a problem where the computer goes to sleep and then can't be re-opened. Really it happens so infrequently I'm not trying to solve the crashing, it's just the unbearable amount of time it takes all my apps and tabs to re-open. I'm dumbfounded that Apple didn't make this optional. (I know about the system preferences and the checkbox you can click during regular reboots, but these appear to be ignored when doing a power-button reboot.)

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention, 15 minutes to boot is way too much, no matter how many apps you have. I haven't seen that boot time since windows XP. 16 GB of ram and a slow hard drive may be your problem, so I'd consider an SSD which will speed your boot time up to 30 seconds.

Also make sure you don't have too many apps in your login items. Remove stuff you can start manually later when you need them.

Finally make sure you have enough drive space, with 16 GB of ram, you need that amount of space to store the ram contents during suspend/resume and other operations.

Anyway, in Lion (tho I recommend Mountain Lion instead) you can disable the Resume of applications straight from the System Preferences (and there are other tricks as well, easy to find).

If you are really going to switch to something other than Snow Leopard, I'd go Mountain Lion. I would venture and say Lion was the Windows Vista of the modern OS Xs :)

Comment: Well the computer boots in 2 or 3 minutes, fairly speedy. It's not about startup-items, it's about the computer stubbornly re-opening everything I already had open and the computer being unresponsive for those 20 minutes while it tries to restore the state where things were when it crashed. This usually includes 10-15 small apps like preview and calculator but also up to 10 BIG apps with lots of open windows like photoshop, dreamweaver, safari (with 10 windows and 50 tabs), firefox, chrome, VM Ware Fusion...

Comment: Understood. The truth is, you can't disable that in Snow Leopard because it was not a system wide feature (as far as I can remember). Apple introduced the Versions/Autosave feature in Lion, which also included the aforementioned "restore" feature. If I don't remember wrong, during Snow Leopard there were a few APIs and each app had to manually implement them. The transition to Lion made it very simple. Apps implementing the feature got the new features automagically. I don't have a SL machine to investigate but I'll look around and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: In any case, my recommendation to switch to an SSD for the OS and apps and leave a regular drive for data still stands. The speed boost will be immense. :)

Comment: If someone tells me that for sure I can disable this behavior in Mountain Lion, that would be reason enough for me to take the plunge. (I do PHP/MySQL development and major OS upgrades are generally a huge pain in the ass, requiring me to recompile all kinds of libraries.)

Comment: In Mountain Lion you can do different things (some "supported" and some not so much). Start by taking a look at this Apple Discussion thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4254982?start=0&tstart=0